# resizing a full-screen html video from both 2 sides

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I finally managed to use a video as full-screen background (withouth position: fixed where you cant scroll), but now i am facing a problem:

1. When changing resolution, the video is still full-screen background but "gets sliced". Is there a way to avoid this from happening and keeping the video being full-screen background without being sliced AND still being able to scroll down? Notice The video is the back. for the land page.
2. If it is not possible (which does look like it bc I haven't found anything out there), I'd like to, at least, make the video "get sliced" from both sides, instead of just the right one which of course is pretty ugly. Even though the video doesn't always stay full-screen (mine does), in this example it gets sliced from both ends: [Example of both-sides slicing](http://www.juanmagonzalez.es/)

Here is the code  have I so far:

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  margin:0;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size:1rem;
  font-weight:normal;
  line-height:1.5;
  color:#333;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}

.v-header{
  height:100vh;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  color:#fff;
}

.container{
  max-width:960px;
  padding-left:1rem;
  padding-right:1rem;
  margin:auto;
  text-align:center;
}

.fullscreen-video-wrap{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.fullscreen-video-wrap video{
  min-height:100%;
  min-width:100%;
}

.header-overlay{
  height:100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100vw;
  z-index:1;
  background:#225470;
  opacity:0.85;
}

.header-content{
  z-index:2;
}

.header-content h1{
  font-size:50px;
  margin-bottom:0;
}

.header-content p{
  font-size:1.5rem;
  display:block;
  padding-bottom:2rem;
}

.btn{
  background: #34b3a0;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:1.2rem;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.section{
  padding:20px 0;
}

.section-b{
  background:#333;
  color:#fff;
}

@media(max-width:960px){
  .container{
    padding-right:3rem;
    padding-left:3rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="v-header container">
    <div class="fullscreen-video-wrap">
      <!--  https://www.videvo.net/video/typing-on-computer-white-bg/4475/ -->
      <!-- DO NOT USE THIS VIDEO, I JUST NEEDED A HOSTED VIDEO FOR THIS CODEPEN> USE THE ONE ABOVE -->
      <video src="../static/video.mp4" autoplay muted loop>
    </video>
    </div>
    <div class="header-overlay"></div>
    <div class="header-content text-md-center">
      <h1>Welcome Everyone</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id temporibus perferendis necessitatibus numquam amet impedit explicabo? Debitis quasi ullam aperiam!</p>
      <a class="btn">Find Out More</a>
    </div>
  </header>

  <section class="section section-a">
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Section A</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde, impedit amet minima iste autem cumque et maiores blanditiis doloribus aut dolorum quaerat non est voluptatum, tempore ut dolorem voluptas quod quae accusantium, ex inventore ducimus. Beatae mollitia exercitationem, quam similique, consectetur ratione reprehenderit delectus neque eligendi facere soluta dolor ducimus!</p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="section section-b">
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Section B</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde, impedit amet minima iste autem cumque et maiores blanditiis doloribus aut dolorum quaerat non est voluptatum, tempore ut dolorem voluptas quod quae accusantium, ex inventore ducimus. Beatae mollitia exercitationem, quam similique, consectetur ratione reprehenderit delectus neque eligendi facere soluta dolor ducimus!</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your first question is no. It is inherently impossible for a video to cover a container with variable/unknown dimensions without being clipped. Since the aspect ratio of the container is variable, and the aspect ratio of the video is intrinsic to the video, they won't always match, and so some portion of the video will not fit into the container sometimes, and need to be clipped.

Here's a solution to your second question, how to center the video so that it is clipped "on both sides": Center the `<video>` in its container with flexbox (or your horizontal and vertical centering methods of choice), and then use the `object-fit: cover` property to make the `<video>` cover its container.

Basically `object-fit` creates the same behavior as `background-size: cover;`. Check out [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) for more info about it, including browser support limitations (no IE yet).

Snippet below has working CSS (the HTML just needs the video src updated to work), with the video covering its whole container and, when it is clipped either vertically or horizontally, it is "clipped on both sides"/remains centered:

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  margin:0;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size:1rem;
  font-weight:normal;
  line-height:1.5;
  color:#333;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}

.v-header{
  height:100vh;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  color:#fff;
}

.container{
  max-width:960px;
  padding-left:1rem;
  padding-right:1rem;
  margin:auto;
  text-align:center;
}

.fullscreen-video-wrap{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  overflow:hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.fullscreen-video-wrap video{
  min-height:100%;
  min-width:100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.header-overlay{
  height:100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100vw;
  z-index:1;
  background:#225470;
  opacity:0.85;
}

.header-content{
  z-index:2;
}

.header-content h1{
  font-size:50px;
  margin-bottom:0;
}

.header-content p{
  font-size:1.5rem;
  display:block;
  padding-bottom:2rem;
}

.btn{
  background: #34b3a0;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:1.2rem;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.section{
  padding:20px 0;
}

.section-b{
  background:#333;
  color:#fff;
}

@media(max-width:960px){
  .container{
    padding-right:3rem;
    padding-left:3rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="v-header container">
    <div class="fullscreen-video-wrap">
      <!--  https://www.videvo.net/video/typing-on-computer-white-bg/4475/ -->
      <!-- DO NOT USE THIS VIDEO, I JUST NEEDED A HOSTED VIDEO FOR THIS CODEPEN> USE THE ONE ABOVE -->
      <video src="../static/video.mp4" autoplay muted loop>
    </video>
    </div>
    <div class="header-overlay"></div>
    <div class="header-content text-md-center">
      <h1>Welcome Everyone</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id temporibus perferendis necessitatibus numquam amet impedit explicabo? Debitis quasi ullam aperiam!</p>
      <a class="btn">Find Out More</a>
    </div>
  </header>

  <section class="section section-a">
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Section A</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde, impedit amet minima iste autem cumque et maiores blanditiis doloribus aut dolorum quaerat non est voluptatum, tempore ut dolorem voluptas quod quae accusantium, ex inventore ducimus. Beatae mollitia exercitationem, quam similique, consectetur ratione reprehenderit delectus neque eligendi facere soluta dolor ducimus!</p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="section section-b">
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Section B</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde, impedit amet minima iste autem cumque et maiores blanditiis doloribus aut dolorum quaerat non est voluptatum, tempore ut dolorem voluptas quod quae accusantium, ex inventore ducimus. Beatae mollitia exercitationem, quam similique, consectetur ratione reprehenderit delectus neque eligendi facere soluta dolor ducimus!</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Works fine, thank you! I'd like to know whether you think it is possible to use a full-screen-background video without ever slicing it when resizing. The thing is, it is a real project, and the people who asked me to do it are obsessed with that... I have been searching all over the internet and I really think there's no such thing, what do you think?

Comment: No it isn't possible. See the first paragraph of my answer starting with "The answer to your first question is no." for an explanation of why.